# How to add Header/Footer in Google Drive from Java API?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, google-drive-api

I converting HTML file to PDF via Google Drive Service. I want to add Header and Footer on pages. How can do that using Java Google Drive API?

PS: If there is not proper way than any workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this directly using Google Drive API. If you are fine with some workaround, I would use [Google Apps Script FooterSection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footer-section):

1. Upload file using [Files.insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) with option convert=true
2. Either trigger or keep running script on specific folder which does the following:
3. Modify Footer using [FooterSection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footer-section)
4. Export Google Document file as PDF

In order to export PDF, there are two ways I can think of.

Using [Document Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getAs) of Apps script

```
doc.getAs("application/pdf")
```

Or getting export link of PDF from Google Drive API using [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) where you can get downloadable link for PDF.

```
"exportLinks": {
    "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={FILE_KEY}&exportFormat=pdf",
    "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={FILE_KEY}&exportFormat=ods",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={FILE_KEY}&exportFormat=xlsx"
   },
```